# Does Qt auto close files?

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

One of the `QIODevice` reimplemented [`open()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#open-2) methods in `QFile` has a `QFileDevice::FileHandleFlag` argument. Taking a look at the documentation for it there are two options with contradicting descriptions.

From the `QFileDevice` [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#FileHandleFlag-enum):

> - `QFileDevice::AutoCloseHandle` – The file handle passed into open() should be closed by close(), the default behavior is that close just flushes the file and the application is responsible for closing the file handle. When opening a file by name, this flag is ignored as Qt always owns the file handle and must close it.
> - `QFileDevice::DontCloseHandle` – If not explicitly closed, the underlying file handle is left open when the QFile object is destroyed.

So does Qt auto close files or not and does setting this option actually change anything?

Comment: The DontCloseHandle is for when the application supplies a *previously opened* handle and Qt piggy-backs on it. In this case the application (not Qt) might want to retain lifetime ownership. Compare this to "*When opening a file by name*, this flag is ignored as *Qt always owns the file handle* and must close it."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking up the Qt source I found the line in [QFSFileEngine.cpp:378](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/io/qfsfileengine.cpp#n378)<sup>*</sup> that ultimately uses the flag.

`QFile::open()` can be passed an existing (`stdio.h`) `FILE` handler which was not created by Qt and shouldn't be automatically closed by Qt. In contrast files opened by Qt are automatically closed by Qt.

The `QFileDevice::FileHandleFlag` flag is for the former case and allows the programmer to specify if `QFile` should auto-close a file ignoring the fact that it was not opened by Qt.

---

******* Search for `closeFileHandle` if the line number doesn't match.